# How Can I Make This List of Checkboxes Into An Unordered List?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a very simple question. I created several checkboxes on a site with labels and I want them to all be vertical. Right now they are all next to each other. I think ideally each box needs to be treated as an ordered list, and then I can adjust it using CSS.

However, using the PHP code in Wordpress, I am having trouble doing this.

The page may be found here: http://www.expeditionersafaris.com/placecategory/all-safaris/?multi_city=15

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Just put the checkboxes inside <ul> tags
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="opt1"> opt1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="opt2"> opt2</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the checkboxes inside an unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li><input ...></li>
  <li><input ...></li>
  <li><input ...></li>
</ul>
```

That will give you some nice SEO-friendly code.

Answer (score 0):

put all your checkboxes inside `<li>` tag like this

```
<ul>
   <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
   <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
   <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```